# Why is my SQL MsAccess query so slow?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Basically I have an SQL query which is an union of 10 queries like the one below. Why is this query so slow? It is taking me more than a minute to run, and it crashes my form when i use a textbox with DCount on this query.

```
SELECT
ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID,
ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID,
ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG,
MIN(ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) AS Data,
MIN(ESP_Facturacao.[1a_Faturado]) AS Valor,
'1 a' AS Tarefa,
'1' AS Control,
min(ESP_Administrativas.Novo_Pos_2010),
min(ESP_SubTipo.Descrição) AS SubTipo,
min(ESP_Unidade.Descricao) AS Unidade,
min(ESP_Facturacao.ID)
FROM ESP_Unidade INNER JOIN (((ESP_TAG LEFT JOIN ESP_Facturacao ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Facturacao.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN (ESP_SubTipo INNER JOIN ESP_Fisico ON ESP_SubTipo.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID) ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN ESP_Administrativas ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Administrativas.ESP_Tag_ID) ON ESP_Unidade.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG) Not In
(SELECT ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG
FROM ESP_Facturacao
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null))))
AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Data_Aut_Funcion) Is Null))
Group By ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG, ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID, ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID, ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG
```

Comment: 1) Are you using any linked tables? 2) Replace the NOT IN phrase of your WHERE clause with an OUTER JOIN and a simpler <> phrase.

Comment: All of the tables are linked. what is a simpler <> phrase?

Comment: Rewrite as a pass-through SQL query instead of using linked tables - your queries will run ~ 100 times, or more, faster. Last time I rewrote a query using linked tables run-time went from 18 ***hours*** to 120 ***seconds***.

Comment: I recently learned to not run a `DCount()` on union queries in MS Access at least 2013 (don't know of other versions) which will crash the app.

Comment: Is your DB indexed efficiently? fields in `Join` and `Where` clause should be indexed for improved query `Select`ion efficiency. Please see also, if giving `ESP_Facturacao` in inner query (in `Where` clause) an alias improves execution.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, what is a pass-through SQL? How can I index my db? Im sorry but Access is really not my thing, I am trying to add a few features to a DB that was built by someone else, and I got stuck with this issue.

Comment: pass-though will ONLY work and apply if you are using SQL server as the backend server. So check indexing on TAG and any other columns used in the join(s).

Comment: I indexed the TAGs and Ive had no noticeable change on speed.

Comment: WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG) Not In
(SELECT ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG
FROM ESP_Facturacao
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null))))
AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Data_Aut_Funcion) Is Null))

I believe this might be the issue, as it is whats causing the biggest lags. Any way to simplify it?

Comment: You are already selecting data from `ESP_Facturacao`, querying the same table again for the `Where` clause is implemented in Access (and most other RDBMS's) in an inefficient way. you should therefor create an alias on the table name in the Inner query: `SELECT AA.Item_TAG FROM ESP_Facturacao As AA WHERE (((AA.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null))`

Comment: Hi @marlan, I think that is exactly what I need. Where would I put that line?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens , how can I replace the not in by an outer join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already selecting data from `ESP_Facturacao`, querying the same table again for the `Where` clause is implemented in Access (as in most other RDBMS's) in an inefficient way. You should therefor create an *[alias](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-FROM-clause-2A7D031C-6912-4E8C-A644-590940DDAED1)* on the table name in the Inner query: `SELECT AA.Item_TAG FROM ESP_Facturacao As AA WHERE (((AA.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null))`:

```
SELECT
ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID,
ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID,
ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG,
MIN(ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) AS Data,
MIN(ESP_Facturacao.[1a_Faturado]) AS Valor,
'1 a' AS Tarefa,
'1' AS Control,
min(ESP_Administrativas.Novo_Pos_2010),
min(ESP_SubTipo.Descrição) AS SubTipo,
min(ESP_Unidade.Descricao) AS Unidade,
min(ESP_Facturacao.ID)
FROM ESP_Unidade INNER JOIN (((ESP_TAG LEFT JOIN ESP_Facturacao ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Facturacao.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN (ESP_SubTipo INNER JOIN ESP_Fisico ON ESP_SubTipo.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID) ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN ESP_Administrativas ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Administrativas.ESP_Tag_ID) ON ESP_Unidade.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG) Not In
(SELECT AA.Item_TAG FROM ESP_Facturacao As AA 
WHERE (((AA.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null))))
AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Data_Aut_Funcion) Is Null))
Group By ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG, ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID, ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID, ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is perfect!